# Problem looping the crossing of parents of a genetic algorithm in python

Tags: python, function, loops, genetic-algorithm

I have the following function in python used to generate the children of a genetic algorithm

```
def cruce(padres):
    mitadHerencia =  len(padres[0])//2
    hijo1 = np.concatenate((padres[0][:mitadHerencia], padres[1][mitadHerencia:]))
    hijo2 = np.concatenate((padres[1][:mitadHerencia], padres[0][mitadHerencia:]))
    hijo3 = np.concatenate((padres[0][:mitadHerencia], padres[2][mitadHerencia:]))
    hijo4 = np.concatenate((padres[2][:mitadHerencia], padres[0][mitadHerencia:]))
    hijo5 = np.concatenate((padres[1][:mitadHerencia], padres[2][mitadHerencia:]))
    return hijo1, hijo2, hijo3, hijo4, hijo5
```

where padres can be defined as

`padres=np.array([[1,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0]],np.int32)`

This is the particular case of a genetic algorithm in which I cross the first element with the second to produce two children, the same with the first and third and so on. I would like to do this using a loop, but I haven't found a way to do this. Can someone please offer me some guidance?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is what I am looking for. I want to mix the vectors so that five new vectors are generated from the first five elements of padres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of tuples for the indices of `padres` and create a list of all `hijo` which can be unpacked when the function returns:

```py
def cruce(padres):
    mitadHerencia =  len(padres[0])//2
    num_offspring = len(padres)//2
    
    parts = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while len(parts) < num_offspring:
        i += 1
        if i >= j:
            i = 0
            j += 1
        parts.extend([(i, j), (j, i)])
    parts = parts[:num_offspring]

    hijo = [np.concatenate((padres[x][:mitadHerencia], padres[y][mitadHerencia:])) for x, y in parts]
    return hijo
```

While I think there exists a cleaner solution to create the parts list, I was unable to. This method iteratively appends the combinations in order and slices it at the end to account for uneven numbers of offspring.

The loop ranges over `j` and increments `i` up to it. If it is equal or greater, it moves on to the next parent. This may be more clear when I show you the output:

```
(0, 1) | (0, 2), (1, 2) | (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3) | (0, 4), ...
```

And of course, we also add the pairs in flipped order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was thinking of scalability. I generate 5 because my sample is of 10, so, if I were working with a sample of 20 I would need 10. The idea is to take half of each padre and create a two hijo, each one having one half of each padre

Comment: So what would be the algorithm that decides which combinations of parents should be selected? I'd be happy to implement that in my solution.

Comment: If you could pick at random from the first half of padres and genetate them, that would be great. If padres were twice the sice (20), then hijos should be of size 10 and created from the 10 first elements of padres. For 40 padres, then 20 hijos generated merging the 20 best padres at random. Sorry if I expressed myself wrongly before

Comment: So I assume that `padres` is sorted by performance in descending order, and the combinations should be the best ones first?

Comment: Yes, I found how to do that beforehand

Comment: I've added what I believe is the solution you're looking for, is this what you wanted?

Comment: I hope so. If it is not, I will try to do it myself